# Questions about bytes billed by google BIGQUERY

Tags: google-bigquery

Can anyone help answer why google BIGQUERY is showing a different number of bytes billed than the bytes processed? in my example, I see from the job information that the bytes processed for my query is 827.93 KB, however the bytes billed is 10 MB? Why google BIGQUERY bills it 10 times more than it processed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BigQuery charges a minimum of 10MB per table even if you have a really small query.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

> Charges are rounded to the nearest MB, with a minimum 10 MB data
>   processed per table referenced by the query, and with a minimum 10 MB
>   data processed per query.

Comment: Do you know if there is a technical rationale behind this 10 MB floor? Like is that the block size used somewhere like by the worker processes? I'm wonder why 10MB, and not 5MB, or 20MB, or some other number. Is it purely a business decision (which is fine), or is there a technical justification?